# Using DateFormatter to return iOS lock screen date style

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

There seem to be five date styles for the DateFormatter class: none, short, medium, long, and full. However, none of these seem to return the lock screen date style, which is as follows:

```
Tuesday, 6 June
```

Using DateFormatter's `.long` style returns the year as well:

```
Tuesday, 6 June 2017
```

Additionally, this lock screen date style will change with the current localization/regional settings.

Is there a way to return the date, à la iOS lock screen date style (along with localizational changes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the localized format for any combination of date components:

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEE MMMM d")

print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // Friday, 4 August
```

In Spanish:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es")
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEE MMMM d")

print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // viernes, 4 de agosto
```

Note how the order of components has been automatically changed and correct separators inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the custom date format "EEEE, d MMMM"

**Swift 3**

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, d MMMM"
dateFormatter.string(from: date)

// Friday, 4 August
```

Comment: I believe the Swift 3 version is `.string(from: date)` instead of `.stringFromDate(date)`